# Responsive HTML (Resize div when window becomes smaller than div)

Tags: html, css

I am curious how this type of responsive layout is achieved (see screenshots).

It looks like the form is in a div that does not start resizing or become responsive until the window has been resized smaller than the div.

I have tried a combination of divs with margins and flex, etc., and have added the `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`  tag to the head as well, but I only manage to make the page responsive to all window resizing.

Any direction here is much appreciated.[image: maxsize] [image: maxsize-div-smaller-window] [image: div-contents-start-resizing] [image: minimum-form-size]

Comment: most likely a simple use of `media queries`. Can also be achieved with `CSS-Grid` and `auto-fill` and `flexbox` and `flex-wrap` + `flex-grow`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple methods of doing this:

**@media queries:**

with media queries, you can define style changes for specific breakpoints. In this case it is used to size a column to 100% width instead of 50% at screen at 480px or lower:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 20px;
}

.container > div {
  width: calc(50% - 20px);
}

@media only screen
  and (max-width: 480px) {
    .container > div {
      width: 100%;
    }
}

input {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <input>
    <label>Firstname</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input>
    <label>Lasttname</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

**flex-grow:**

This Flexbox approach defines the max-width of a column to 480px. If an element is smaller than 480px it will span the entire given width. `flex-wrap: wrap` is used to push the 2nd column to the next row. For screens larger than 960 px (2 columns), `flex-grow` will overwrite the `max-width` and allow the element to occupy the remaining available space.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 20px;
}

.container > div {
  width: 480px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

input {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <input>
    <label>Firstname</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input>
    <label>Lasttname</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS-Grid + auto-fit:**

This Grid solution uses `minmax` and `auto-fit` to create columns dynamically. It will fit as many columns as possible but ensures that no column is less then 480px (unless the screen is smaller) and resize the columns to occupy remaining space.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(480px, 1fr));
  gap: 20px;
}

input {
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <input>
    <label>Firstname</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input>
    <label>Lasttname</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I almost want to combine this with erfan’s approach. I don’t want the form area to take full width until the window/screen size is smaller than the initial width. Does that make sense?

Comment: you can of course limit the width of the container with `max-width`.

Comment: Feel like I learned a lot here, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

by set `width: 100%;` and `max-width` to any value like `max-width: 400px;` you can do this

```css
.my-div {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 400px;
  
  /* center */
  margin-inline: auto;
  
  /* just for demo */
  background: #808080;
  height: 50em;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-div"></div>
```

Comment: This will not make them occupy all available space nor will it allow the elements to be next to each other and wrap at smaller screens. if you have a screen with a 1920px width then only 800px will be sued.